# extract value from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the dataframe

> 

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': ['Get URI||1621992600749||com.particlenews.newsbreak||https://graph.fb.com||2021-05-26 01:30:00||1.3.0-QA-1100||90',
              'Get URI||1621992600799||com.particlenews.newsbreak||https://graph.fb.com||2021-05-26 01:30:00||1.3.0-QA-1100||90']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and need to extract the "1621992600749" and "1621992600799" values.

i have done it multiple ways , by using the split function

```
new = df["col1"].str.split("||", n = 1, expand = True)
```

but doesnt give the expected results, any thoughts will be helpful.

Comment: `df['col1'].str.split('\|\|', expand=True)`? What are your expected results?

Comment: `df['col1'].str.split('\|\|', expand=True)[1]` or `df['col1'].str.split('\|\|').str[1]` to just get that specific element.

Answer (score 1):

You cna use the extract with regex

```
df['col1'].str.extract(r'(\d+)')

#output

    0
0   1621992600749
1   1621992600799
```